# COUNTIFS formula that matches multiple strings

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to create a simple COUNTIFS formula that matches two strings. The answer should be "2" but I'm getting a #VALUE! error.

This is what I have:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$6,"Positive",$B$2:$F$6,"a")
```

Comment: What does the data look like?

Comment: Your ranges must be the same size.  You will need to do separate countifs() for each column and add them together.

Comment: I didn't realize the ranges had to be the same size. Thanks for the insight. This worked: =SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A6="Positive")*--(B2:F6="a"))

Comment: If you are going to multiply the Booleans you do not need the `--`.  That is only needed if you only have one Boolean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With COUNTIFS() the ranges must be the same size.  So you will need to do multiple COUNTIFS() and sum them together:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$6,"Positive",$B$2:$B$6,"a")+COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$6,"Positive",$C$2:$C$6,"a")+...
```

Or use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$6="positive")*($B$2:$F$6="a"))
```

which does not have such restrictions.